# Jasmine hanging while uses a sails instance

Tags: testing, jasmine, sails.js

I have this simple test and helper https://gist.github.com/charly-palencia/37e808ead2946c223727

But, every time I run my test, jasmine is hanging after run the test.

I search for the sails process with **ps aux** and it's not up.

I'm new in sails and I have no idea what it's happening with this. would you might helping with that?